# Need bordered circle with different color around user's location

Tags: android, android-layout, android-maps, android-maps-v2

Please apologize if my question is too simple.

I am developing an android app in which I display users location in a map. I am also displaying a circle around the user's point.

My code for this in ItemizedOverlay is:

```
    public void setGeoPoints(GeoPoint theGeoPoints, int theCircleRadius) 
    {
        this.itsGeoPoints = theGeoPoints;
        itsPaint = new Paint();
        itsPaint.setARGB(10, 0, 0, 205);
        this.itsCircleRadius = theCircleRadius;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas theCanvas, MapView theMapView, boolean shadow) 
    {
        super.draw(theCanvas, theMapView, shadow);
        Point pt = theMapView.getProjection().toPixels(itsGeoPoints, null);
        float projectedRadius = theMapView.getProjection().metersToEquatorPixels(itsCircleRadius);
        theCanvas.drawCircle(pt.x, pt.y, projectedRadius, itsPaint);
    }
```

Using the above code, I get a blue circle around the user's location perfectly.

Now, I need to have a border for the circle with different color.  That is, a circle with bold border (different color).

Any help on this please.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a separate `Paint` object with [STROKE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.Style.html) style set using `Paint.setStyle` and different color.

When you have that just call `drawCircle` again with this new `Paint`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks MaciejGórski!

```
    public void setGeoPoints(GeoPoint theGeoPoints, int theCircleRadius) 
    {
        this.itsGeoPoints = theGeoPoints;

        itsPaint1 = new Paint();
        itsPaint1.setARGB(150, 0, 0, 255);
        itsPaint1.setStyle(Style.STROKE);

        itsPaint2 = new Paint();
        itsPaint2.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        itsPaint2.setARGB(5, 0, 0, 200);
        this.itsCircleRadius = theCircleRadius;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas theCanvas, MapView theMapView, boolean shadow) 
    {
        super.draw(theCanvas, theMapView, shadow);

        Point pt = theMapView.getProjection().toPixels(itsGeoPoints, null);
        float projectedRadius = theMapView.getProjection().metersToEquatorPixels(itsCircleRadius);

        theCanvas.drawCircle(pt.x, pt.y, projectedRadius, itsPaint1);
        theCanvas.drawCircle(pt.x, pt.y, projectedRadius, itsPaint2);
    }
```